# dplyr - Sort str_flatten vector column

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science, tidyr

I was searching alot but I cannot solve this situation:

I'm using select in dplyr to get elements from a sql database

**my data structure looks like:**

```
"player_id_in_match","player_code","hero_name","game_timestamp","match_code"
1, player_rafael_0, hero_0, 1510000, game_001
1, player_rafael_0, hero_1, 1510000, game_001
1, player_rafael_0, hero_1, 1510000, game_001
2, player_rafael_0, hero_1, 1510000, game_002
2, player_rafael_0, hero_0, 1510000, game_002
2, player_rafael_0, hero_1, 1510000, game_002
3, player_jack_0, hero_5, 1510000, game_004
4, player_james_0, hero_2, 1510000, game_001
5, player_john_0, hero_1, 1510000, game_006
```

**I would like to group hero_name in team:**

```
"player_code","team","match_code"
player_rafael_0, hero_0,hero_1,hero_1, game_001
player_rafael_0, hero_0,hero_1,hero_1, game_002
player_jack_0, hero_5, game_004
player_james_0, hero_2, game_001
player_jack_0, hero_1, game_006
```

**Then group again if the team is the same**

```
"player_code","team","repeat_x_times"
player_rafael_0, hero_0,hero_1,hero_1, 2
player_jack_0, hero_5, 1
player_james_0, hero_2, 1
player_jack_0, hero_1, 1
```

**What I tryed:**

```
connect sql & joins to -> data
...
proc_data <- data %>%
select("player_id_in_match","player_code","hero_name","game_timestamp","match_code")%>%
group_by(player_id_in_match)%>%
summarise(player_code, team = str_flatten(hero_name, collapse =", "))%>%
mutate(repeated = 1)%>%
group_by(team,player_code) %>%
summarise(player_code, team,repeat_x_times = sum(repeated )) %>%
ungroup()%>%
select(player_code, team, repeat_x_times ) %>%
collect()
```

**The problem:**

apparently everything is fine, but it's not grouping because the order of "hero_name" is different, and it doesn't group

```
hero_0, hero_0, hero_1
with
hero_1, hero_0, hero_0
```

It may be a mistake in some other part of the code, but I believe that only one "sort (desc (team))" will solve it, but I'm not finding a way to do this using str_flatten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'am not sure if this is exactly what you want, but I adjusted your code a bit. You can specify a column name in `summarise`. If you want to keep that column you have to add it to `group_by`. I also sorted on `hero_name` to make sure the order is the same.

```
proc_data <- data %>%
  select(player_id_in_match, player_code, hero_name, game_timestamp, match_code) %>%
  group_by(player_id_in_match, player_code) %>% # added player_code
  arrange(hero_name) %>%  # did a sort here
  summarise(team = str_flatten(hero_name, collapse =", ")) %>%
  mutate(repeated = 1) %>%
  group_by(team, player_code) %>%
  summarise(repeat_x_times = sum(repeated)) %>%  # removed team and player_code
  ungroup() %>%
  select(player_code, team, repeat_x_times ) %>%
  collect()
```

This was my result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  player_code     team                   repeat_x_times
  <chr>           <chr>                           <dbl>
1 player_rafael_0 hero_0, hero_1, hero_1              2
2 player_john_0   hero_1                              1
3 player_james_0  hero_2                              1
4 player_jack_0   hero_5                              1
```

Cheers, Rico

Comment: Thank you, for the clear answer Rico, you got the point!
I did the changes but still not sorting.

When I run in the database, I saw that data isnt sorted yet in some cases like:

team:
Android, Ashen, Vaine, Soulblast, Nassus, Jax, Bramus

Cheers, Rafael :)

Comment: Fixed it, in data I did a arrange too, and collect()
and start working <3
Thanks